# Как забрать дамп БД с аварийного сервера?

Tags: mysql, linux, администрирование, восстановление

Всем привет. На удалённом выделенном сервере сломался 1 из 2-х винчестеров и сервер умер. Т.к. винты были в RAID, я зашёл на сервер в rescue режиме и примонтировал живой винт. Хочу забрать БД с него, но в rescue mode обычные команды не работают, команды `mysqldump` там нет.
Как в этом случае забрать БД?
Знаю, что БД физически хранится в папке `/mnt/var/lib/mysql/DBName`.
Скажите, можно просто скопировать файлы `*.frm` `*.MYI` `*.MYD` а затем поместить их по тому же пути в новом сервере? Можно так базы данных переносить? Будет нормально работать? Есть какие-либо подводные камни такого переноса?

Comment: *можно просто скопировать файлы .frm .MYI .MYD а затем поместить их по тому же пути в новом сервере?* Можно, конечно, но потом присоединение их к серверу превратится в увлекательный, но весьма геморройный, квест. Копируйте полностью весь datadir. Им можно подменить datadir рабочего сервера (при остановленном, само собой, демоне, и строго той же версии) и получить доступ к данным для выполнения бэкапа штатными средствами.

Comment: Подтверждаю, копируйте всю папку var/lib/mysql. На сервере с тестовым mysql (не рабочим!) подложите ее целиком и оттуда уже сделайте dump нужных БД. Но учтите, что оставлять и использовать в рабочем режиме такие данные крайне не рекомендуется. То есть сохранили в дамп и восстановили потом на нормальном рабочем сервере - вот так можно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну я бы посоветовал копировать диск утилитой [dd](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd).

Но если вы знаете что копировать...

Точное место расположения БД MYSQL можно посмотреть в конфигах:

```
grep datadir /etc/my.cnf
grep -r datadir /etc/mysql/
```

должно выдать что-то вроде

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

или вот так

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
```

На всякий бывает полезно убедиться что mysql не запущен:

```
ps -eo cmd,args | grep mysql  # на Linux
ps -ao pid,command | grep mysql  # на BSD
```

Копировать с правами лучше утилитой tar

```
tar -cf /tmp/mysql.tar /var/lib/mysql
```